# QML Pathview how to slide through icons

Tags: path, qml

I have the following requirement and can't find the right way in.

A maximum of 5 icons from a list of icons should be displayed.

At the start, the first icon from the list should be in the middle of the container.
With left arrow button click, the next icon is placed in the middle and the first moves to the left.

At the end of the list, the last icon remains in the middle. The icons to the right and left of the center should be smaller than the icon in the center.

Start:

[image]

Middle:

[image]

End:

[image]

The pathview works so far, the icons come from a c++ class and are displayed via the delegate.

I have the path block from an example, but it won't fit directly to this and I don't understand yet what exactly is defined here.

Do I need maybe 5 PathAttribute blocks and 4 PathLine? How do i start with the first icon in the middle? How can I change the size of the icons depending on their position and how can I get them closer together

I would be very happy about any help to get started

Coverflow.qml

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    height: 200
    width: 400      
    Layout.preferredHeight: height 
    Layout.preferredWidth: width
    color: "white"
    
    PathView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        pathItemCount: 5
        
        model: m_screen.coverflowModel
        delegate: CoverflowDelegate { height: view.height; width: view.height; p_icon: icon; p_z: PathView.iconOrder }
        
        path: Path {
            startX: 0; startY: view.height/2
            PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 0.6 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 0.9 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: 90}
            PathLine {x: view.width / 2; y: view.height/2 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 1 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 1 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: 0 }
            PathLine {x: view.width; y: view.height/2 }
            PathAttribute { name: "itemScale"; value: 0.6  }
            PathAttribute { name: "itemOpacity"; value: 0.9 }
            PathAttribute { name: "angle"; value: -90 }
        }
    }
 }
```

CoverflowDelegate.qml

```
Item {
    id: delegate
    property string p_icon
    property string p_source: (!p_icon || p_icon.length === 0)  ? "" : "image://iconprovider/" + p_icon
    property int p_z
    Rectangle {
        color: "lightgrey"
        width: 70; height: 70
        radius: 10
        z: p_z
        Image {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: p_source
            sourceSize.width: parent.width * 0.8
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT/REWRITE to use highlightRangeMode]

You could mock this up with a `ListView` + `Button`. We can configure the `ListView` with:

```
    height: 120
    width: 600 // i.e. height * 5
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
    preferredHighlightBegin: width / 2
    preferredHighlightEnd: width / 2
```

The `ListView` will take care of the horizontal scrolling and snapping to item to create a clean animation and user experience.

The `highlightRangeMode`, `preferredHighlightBegin`, `preferredHighlightEnd` properties ensured that the highlighted item is always in the center of the `ListView`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: height * 5
        height: 120
        clip: true
        model: MyListModel { id: listModel }
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        preferredHighlightBegin: width / 2
        preferredHighlightEnd: width / 2
        delegate: MyDelegate { }
    }
}

// MyDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Item {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    property bool isCurrentItem: ListView.isCurrentItem
    property int dist: Math.abs(listView.width / 2 + listView.contentX - (x + width / 2))
    width: height
    height: listView.height
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        //visible: !dummy
        width: parent.height / (1 + dist * 0.002)
        height: width
        background: Rectangle {
            radius: 10
            border.color: "#888"
            color: isCurrentItem ? "#ccc" : "#eee"
        }
        icon.source: ico
        icon.width: parent.width * .6
        icon.height: parent.height * .6
        icon.color: isCurrentItem ? "black" : "#888"
        Label {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            y: parent.height * 3 / 4
            text: nam
            visible: !dummy
            color: "#08f"
            z: 2
        }
    }
}

// MyListModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ListModel {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        append( { nam: "One", ico: "target.svg", val: 1 } );
        append( { nam: "Two", ico: "pencil.svg", val: 2 } );
        append( { nam: "Three", ico: "monitor.svg", val: 3 } );
        append( { nam: "Four", ico: "target.svg", val: 4 } );
        append( { nam: "Five", ico: "pencil.svg", val: 5 } );
        append( { nam: "Six", ico: "monitor.svg", val: 6 } );
        append( { nam: "Seven", ico: "target.svg", val: 7 } );
        append( { nam: "Eight", ico: "pencil.svg", val: 8 } );
    }
}

// target.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="8" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="black" d="M 16 12 L 15 11 L 15 6 L 17 6 L 17 11 z" />
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="black" d="M 20 16 L 21 15 L 26 15 L 26 17 L 21 17 z"/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="black" d="M 16 20 L 17 21 L 17 26 L 15 26 L 15 21 z "/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="black" d="M 12 16 L 11 17 L 6 17 L 6 15 L 11 15 z"/>
</svg>

// monitor.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<rect stroke="black" fill="none" x="5" y="7" width="22" height="14" rx="1"/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" fill="black" d="M 2 23 L 30 23 L 30 24 L 29 25 L 3 25 L 2 24 z L 14 23.5 L 14 24.5 L 18 24.5 L 18 23.5 L 14 23.5"/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" fill="black" d="M 22 13 L 23 13 L 23 15 L 10 15 L 10 15.8 L 8 14.5 L 10 13.2 L 10 14 L 22 14 z
"/>
</svg>

// pencil.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent" d="M 24 18 L 24 25
A 1 1 0 0 1 23 26 L 5 26 A 1 1 0 0 1 4 25 L 4 7 A 1 1 0 0 1 5 6 L 23 6 A 1 1 0 0 1 24 7 L 24 10"/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="black" d="M 27 13 L 25 11 L 26 10 A 1 1 0 0 1 27 10 L 28 11 A 1 1 0 0 1 28 12 z
"/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="black" d="M 26 14 L 21 19 L 19 17 L 24 12 z"/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="transparent" d="M 21 19 L 20 20 L 18 20 L 18 18 L 19 17" />
<rect x="18" y="19" width="1" height="1" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAOWHicpVZbc5tGFH7nV5ySFzttECAkYTVKp3bcSWbsaZN0On1FsJZ2jFh1WV0z/u89B5aFlW25rhiPznLu354L5oulkAq+qC8rnt473Hr1rkShpMhL549kxuC7A/jc8FL9xdlGv9KTFOlcyNJLWaGY/FyMYZlIPBuFDc/UfAxzxmdzBW9hYCQ1awxB6BtemvPlGJRcMcNaiIzlY7jdUfRbeoHvwLMx5Ob9wSgLyTF4orjATJp0vU/I3iOeJG+DY+yc4n9NihkjNx39b0ryVOW76+JOyJRVKsZyKdkdk5JlnxoXl2zGMVyFFHoQHlG9LrKnFBEEmyWKEcyP+owoa1wPzoPj9HodkffPIj+o17Pl+6zYQtdrKcWSSbVr65jrQwf7Gn9s7akQOfDyaiWpsOSvo27xbTteKMhQD0Elau4l0/KsieeZK4AfTRJeijmjp7/hHZxtUWCUzs+dR63kdFvIuOjILldKieI1rdrrrXnJpzmW4YdstVjsDpu41tdBMLGzALMkiNjXvuf74fmj5q4sDXeapPczKVbUBV9ZqrCxctZJkR6ZZHxV4lj4FnsqZMYk3lEu5BjcN3Ecu5aCllgFgV9QM01TF8iEMdaatDPD8d69Uqyw08f0Ygts6HVJ3oI3tLUauPYNPdZ7LslpjjdTZ2kBu0mmNO8W0KaOczPVV1VF2+gHAst69zjJPpYyspQU2yKYIllY3Oe6o3P77hs/vrPrsh93Bv1wos1Oe81IdxZh5e5KoGJBkERB55wphg3W6fzlkhXZGW4UhIRJ/l4w9ycqCJ5VImdMeeV6hqx1gps2gAc4//lZ4z83whijJOV51zh8wXguWRt7IQquhOza94/b/4ZteiT16AVrvmZHch8ct/7Gt8cyH75gzdasOJL66Lj5NfXqkdzj1rzprjaG8x5/YLvIi3LizpVajnu9zQa3cN8TctYLfd/vkS+g5X8pthPXBx/6If65H5z3KZcprqkU+cHQhXRXUzlxYxdK7Ml7NmkmuH59V+0JVHPhjuf5xC2wP13oobMlfguOG/neoDHT8mzi3kIwxP8U4AaCAQRBTYdERg1B7v7EGKFPYW4gDMg90mFLR5o/wiinAsE4VcphoOmwBmQoQoETo4Q1lCCoUx8aMtDcgQZCpf9QdUynq09sGYkft8O0u52A+pg1NtLIBY0jDF391cS+ibC9qN3+8x0ET5YTwj6C7fstjaiKFxDSJfRrEhJ3T5cSoZ430KeoPsXdUyvF04m5YX0oKczM0Mq536FejKcYA3oNq++F+lQhCYnunYM6tuvhxDK+jM5gUzIpyvrL2iCM6M5uiIYD51f8rgRA3gPCWnV61fBdQVRXJMJt2GXXk45WtnZIepX/wD9tWMKRLoLeLTTvvh1rRByUxKRhSWKaNV2D/5/BUFcUHV9QhS/0xokq7693/kQ9tGtcPvX+iQ2t6lSFrBdoNb40f3E1pMGFmdKgM6Q2DtOC/wKYnAQw)

Comment: This is a pretty cool solution. I have only found approaches with the PathView. Does your solution have any limitations compared to a PathView solution? 
And how do I get it to start with the 0 in the middle and only 1 and 2 are displayed to the right of it?

Comment: You have great approaches. I have added four, but due to the visible = false, number 2 is still displayed on the far left and not in the middle? Could you otherwise try it once in your online example?

And another question - can you position the icon in the button at the top instead of in the middle of the button?

Comment: The problem is that the selected button moves to the left or right, but it should be fixed in the middle.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `highlightRangeMode` instead.